# MVC view code for bool type input

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In one of my first MVC projects I encountered the following part of code in my "Create" view.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attend, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Attend)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Attend, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This was scaffolded based on the following property in my model:

```
public virtual bool? Attend { get; set; }
```

What this will show for me on the "Create" view is a dropdown with the following values: Not Set; True; False;

Is there a way I can change these values in the dropdownlist for my bool so that it says something more readable/understandable for a user like: Yes; No;?

I tried to search for a solution and I think it has something to do with the following line:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Attend)
```

Comment: You could create your own `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (`Value="true", Text="Yes"` etc) and use `@Html.DropDownListFor()`

Answer (score 2):

As @Stephen Muecke said you can create your own selectlist. You can do it with your own editor template .

Here is how i have done it:

Create `EditorTeplates` folder in `Views/Shared`

Create `YesNoNotSelected.cshtml` in this folder with this code:

```
@model bool?

@Html.DropDownList("", new SelectListItem[] 
{ 
    new SelectListItem() 
    { 
        Text = "Not set", 
        Value = String.Empty, 
        Selected = !Model.HasValue
    }, 
    new SelectListItem() 
    { 
        Text = "True", 
        Value = "true", 
        Selected = Model.HasValue && Model.Value 
    }, 
    new SelectListItem() 
    { 
        Text = "False", 
        Value = "false", 
        Selected = Model.HasValue && !Model.Value 
    } 
})
```

In your model add [`UIHintAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.uihint(v=vs.110).aspx) above `Attend` property like this:

```
[UIHint("YesNoNotSelected")]
public virtual bool? Attend { get; set; }
```

Now `EditorFor` helper should render your property according to this template.

Comment: Stephen was talking about creating your own list of options, not a new helper, and what you have here is an editor template, not a helper. Helpers are extensions to `HtmlHelper`. Also, FWIW, if you want all bools handled the same way, you can simply name your editor template `Boolean.cshtml`, and then there's no need for `UIHint`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt i suppose that he don't want to handle all nullable bools same way, and i agree it's not helper, but editor template, my bad

Comment: Yeah, I know. My comment was mostly for the OP, just so he doesn't end up adding `UIHint` to every bool across his app, just because he wants that editor template.

Answer (score 0):

I like the best of all worlds scenario:

1. I don't want to always require a UIHint
2. I don't want to use UIHint at all, it's not descriptive
3. I want bools to be extensible; yes/no, true/false, etc

Here is how I implemented it:

/Models/BooleanType.cs

```
public enum BooleanDisplay
{
  undefined = 0,
  YesNo = 1,
  TrueFalse = 2,
  GoodEvil = 3
}
```

/MVC/UIBooleanType.cs

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class UIBooleanAttribute : UIHintAttribute
  :base("boolean", "MVC")
{
  public UIBoolean(BooleanType displayAs)
  {
    DisplayAs = displayAs;
  }

  public BooleanDisplay DisplayAs { get; set; }
}
```

/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/boolean.cshtml

```
@model boolean?

@{
  // default
  var displayAs = BooleanDisplay.TrueFalse;

  var uiBoolean = ViewData
    .ModelMetadata
    .ContainerType
    .GetProperty(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName)
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UIBooleanAttribute))
    .Select(ca => ca as UIBooleanAttribute)
    .FirstOrDefault(ca => ca != null);

  if (uiBoolean != null)
  {
    displayAs = uiBoolean.DisplayAs;
  }

  var values = new List<SelectListItem>()
  { 
    new SelectListItem() 
    { 
      Text = "Not set", 
      Value = String.Empty, 
      Selected = !Model.HasValue
    }
  };

  switch(displayAs)
  {
    default:
      throw new NotImplementedException(displayAs.ToString() 
        + " is not implemented in boolean.cshtml";
    YesNo:
      values.Add(new SelectListItem() 
      { 
        Text = "Yes", 
        Value = "true", 
        Selected = Model.HasValue && Model.Value 
      });
      values.Add(new SelectListItem() 
      { 
        Text = "No", 
        Value = "false", 
        Selected = Model.HasValue && !Model.Value 
      });
    TrueFalse: 
      // etc
  }
}

@Html.DropDownList("", values)
```

usage:

ViewModel:

```
public class Person
{
  // defaults to True/False
  public bool AreYouHappy { get; set; }

  [UIBoolean(BooleanDisplay.GoodEvil)]
  public bool IsInherently { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Person

@Html.EditorFor(p => p.AreYouHappy)

@Html.EditorFor(p => p.IsInherently)
```

Comment: i'm not sure, is this approach really better, then mine? I thought @ChrisPratt was talking about owerloding drop down list with `bool?`, this doesn't look pretty...

Comment: I did replace the editor template, the UIBoolean is not required, there are no ["magic" strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string) anywhere to determine the type e.g. `UIHint("MagicString")` and all boolean logic is encapsulated inside a single view.  It's not better, it's simply more advanced.

Comment: but, i mean, you know 1 magic string vs x3 codelines and working with `ModelMetadata` on View but not in helper method.

Comment: Helper methods are good, but there is no other way to override a default boolean.  A helper method, like `Html.DisplayBooleanFor()`, could be used but it becomes [tribal knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribal_knowledge) and that isn't the convention for Editor Templates.  ModelMetadata is exact designed for adding meta data to a model, Watermark, etc, I'm using it exactly as it was intended (and how MVC uses it internally).